# Build android app on azure Pipelines error MSB4044: The "AndroidSignPackage" task was not given a value for the required parameter "KeyPass"

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maui

I am creating a Pipelines to have the files to download on Android app, and as soon as I build with MSBuild it tells me error `error MSB4044: The "AndroidSignPackage" task was not given a value for the required parameter "KeyPass".` because I didn't put the password of the Keypass in my csproj as it's recommended in the maui doc so how can I do to give the password without it being in clear.

the MSBuild in YAML

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" /p:AppxBundle=Never p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="" /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(signingCert.secureFilePath)"'
```

the csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>myapp.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>key</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass></AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass></AndroidSigningStorePass>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It seems there are a few things mixed up here. In the top piece of YAML you also add msbuild arguments for your Windows build? If you don't want to specify a value in the csproj then take the tag out of the cpsroj file and provide it as an argument like you do in the line with `msbuildArgs`. Additionally you probably want to build through `dotnet build` and not msbuild

Comment: @GeraldVersluis how I take the tag out of the cpsroj file

Comment: Remove the `<AndroidSigningKeyPass></AndroidSigningKeyPass>` line

Comment: no it does not change anything to delete it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This was resolved by filling the Allias password at Properties -> Android -> Package Signing.